# TextView in custom GridView adapter does not update, but ImageView does

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

I have a custom `GridView` adapter that takes an `AudioGridItem` object as a parameter in its constructor. So basically each object has 2 `ImageView`s and 1 `TextView`. When I delete a grid position, using a long click listener, it should erase the file (on SD card) then put a placeholder drawable in the place of the previous image (`Uri`). It should also set the `TextView` to an empty `String`. But this does not work. The `ImageView`s update, but the `TextView` title of the file still lingers in the old spot. This results in everything in the `ArrayList` moving up a spot, yet the titles of the file are still in the old spot. Yet, curiously, when I switch to my photo tab, then return to my audio tab, the `TextView` updates properly (but it won't update when I switch to the video or write tab, strange.)

I do clear both my adapter and my `ArrayList` before I reload everything (re-run the `AsyncTask`).

I have seen other posts on here about this problem, but have not found anything that works for me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20567843/textview-not-updating-when-deleting-record-in-custom-adapter) one talks about using the right `TextView`, but I only have one, and am using it right. That said, some other code involving my `TextView` is probably incorrect? It's the only thing I can think of since I use `notifyDataSetChanged()` all over the place, so I know my adapter is updated (plus the `ImageView`s change, so that's a hint). The logic I am using in my long click listener is to:

1. Delete the file at position on the SD card
2. Clear my both my adapter and list (then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`)
3. Reload from SD card from scratch by calling `AsyncTask` again

Any ideas? As you can see in the photo, the highlighted icons are the ones that have a sound file and a drawable attached to their `ImageView`s (which play correctly), but the darker icons are the ones that are placeholders, and the file I tried to long click to delete, shows the placeholder icon (as it should) but also that lingering title in the `TextView`. How do I get rid of this?

[image]

**AudioTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.audiotab;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

import org.azurespot.R;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class AudioTab extends Fragment {

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAudioAdapter audioAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private String[] numberSDCardFiles = null;
    File[] files;
    ArrayList<AudioGridItem> audioFiles = new ArrayList<>();
    AudioGridItem audioGridItem;
    AudioGridItem drawable;
    AudioGridItem drawableSound;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Uri drawableOff;
    String audioTitle;

    public AudioTab(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_tab, container, false);

        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        // instantiate your progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.audio_grid);
        // Create the Custom Adapter Object
        audioAdapter = new GridViewAudioAdapter(getActivity(), audioFiles);
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(audioAdapter);

        if(audioAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            // load contents of SD card through AsyncTask
            new AudioDownloaderTask().execute();
        }

        setupGridViewListener();


        return v;
    }

    private class AudioDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, AudioGridItem> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading cute collection ...");
            //set the progress bar to cancelable on back button
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected AudioGridItem doInBackground(Object... params) {

            retrieveAudio();

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AudioGridItem result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            // add sound off drawable to replace song files when there are none
            for (int i = 0; i < (15 - numberSDCardFiles.length); i++) {
                audioAdapter.add(drawable);
            }

            audioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

    public void retrieveAudio() {

        // creates a new AudioGridItem object with this drawable as the source
        drawableSound = new AudioGridItem(null, getResources().getDrawable
                (R.drawable.ic_sounds_placeholder_on), null);

        try {
            // gets directory Cute Videos from sd card
            File cuteVideosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS), "Cute Sounds");

            // puts list into files Array
            files = cuteVideosDir.listFiles();

            // get number of files in Cute Sounds directory
            numberSDCardFiles =  new String[files.length];

            for (File singleFile : files) {
                // get both audio file and audio title
                Uri audioUri = Uri.fromFile(singleFile);
                audioTitle = singleFile.getName();

                // get sound on drawable from object
                Drawable drawableOn = drawableSound.getDrawable();

                // since in a loop, sound on drawable will be added same as files
                audioGridItem = new AudioGridItem(audioUri, drawableOn, audioTitle);

                // add Uri, drawable (sound on) and title to ArrayList
                audioFiles.add(audioGridItem);
            }

            // put sound off drawable into an AudioGridItem object (as Uri, no Drawable or String)
            drawableOff = Uri.parse("android.resource://org.azurespot/drawable/"
                                                            + R.drawable.ic_sounds_placeholder);
            drawable = new AudioGridItem(drawableOff, null, null);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void setupGridViewListener() {
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView,
                                    View item, int pos, long id) {

                AudioGridItem currentItem = audioAdapter.getItem(pos);

                mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                });

                if(!(audioAdapter.getItem(pos).equals(drawable))) {

                    if(currentItem == audioAdapter.getItem(pos)) {

                        if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                            mp.reset();
                        }
                        else {
                            Uri soundFile = (audioAdapter.getItem(pos)).getAudio();
                            try {
                                mp.setDataSource(getActivity(), soundFile);
                                mp.prepare();
                                mp.start();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else{

                        Uri soundFile = (audioAdapter.getItem(pos)).getAudio();
                        try {
                            mp.setDataSource(getActivity(), soundFile);
                            mp.prepare();
                            mp.start();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        });

        // to delete a Uri item
        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> aView, View item,
                                           final int pos, long id) {

                mp.reset();

                // insures the placeholder drawable is not clickable
                if (!(audioAdapter.getItem(pos)).equals(drawable)) {

                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                            .setTitle("Delete")
                            .setMessage("Delete this cute sound?")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // delete from ArrayList first
                                    audioFiles.remove(pos);

                                    // get file name then delete it from SD card
                                    String name = files[pos].getName();
                                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                                            (Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS), "Cute Sounds" + "/" + name);
                                    file.delete();

                                    audioGridItem.setAudioTitle(" ");

                                    // after each item delete, replace with default icon, and empty String
                                    audioAdapter.add(new AudioGridItem(drawableOff, null, null));

                                    // clear old list first
                                    audioAdapter.clear();
                                    audioFiles.clear();
                                    audioAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    // reload all files, so positioning is right when open it
                                    new AudioDownloaderTask().execute();

                                    Log.d("TAG", "Reached after async runs again.");

                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    // do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            })
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .show();
                }

                return true;
            }

        });

    }
}
```

**GridViewAudioAdapter.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.audiotab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.azurespot.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class GridViewAudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AudioGridItem> {

    private TextView audioTitleView;
    int position;
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    Context context;
    String rootName;


    public GridViewAudioAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<AudioGridItem> audio) {
        super(context, 0, audio);
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View itemView, ViewGroup parent) {

        this.position = position;

        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.audio_tab_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.audioViewFile = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_file);
            holder.audioViewIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_icon);
            audioTitleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);

            // stores holder with view
            itemView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder)itemView.getTag();
        }


        // get position of the item clicked in GridView
        final AudioGridItem audioGridItem = getItem(position);

        if (audioGridItem != null) {

            // getting the Uri from here might give a file or the off drawable
            Uri audioUri = audioGridItem.getAudio();
            // this will only ever be the on drawable
            Drawable drawableOn = audioGridItem.getDrawable();

            // set text
            String audioTitle = audioGridItem.getAudioTitle();
            if (audioTitle != null) {
                rootName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(audioTitle);
                audioTitleView.setText(rootName);
            } else
                audioTitleView.setText(" ");

            // set the Uri or drawable into the ImageView slots
            holder.audioViewFile.setImageURI(audioUri);
            holder.audioViewIcon.setImageDrawable(drawableOn);


            // positioning the file Uri in the GridView slot
            holder.audioViewFile.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.audioViewFile.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
                    (220, 220));

            // positioning the drawable icon in the GridView slot
            holder.audioViewIcon.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            holder.audioViewIcon.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams
                    (220, 220));

        }

        return itemView;

    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        ImageView audioViewFile;
        ImageView audioViewIcon;
    }
}
```

**AudioGridItem.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection.audiotab;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 4/26/15.
 */
public class AudioGridItem {

    private Uri audio;
    private String audioTitle;
    Drawable drawableOn;

    public AudioGridItem(Uri audio, Drawable drawable, String autoTitle) {
        super();
        this.audio = audio;
        this.drawableOn = drawable;
        this.audioTitle = autoTitle;
    }

    public Uri getAudio() {

        return audio;
    }

    public void setAudio(Uri audio){

        this.audio = audio;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(){

        return drawableOn;
    }

    public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable){

        this.drawableOn = drawable;
    }

    public String getAudioTitle(){

        return audioTitle;
    }

    public void setAudioTitle(String audioTitle){

        this.audioTitle = audioTitle;

    }

}
```

Comment: im back again.. Sir/madam, why do you need `files` whatever your `files` can do for you `audioFiles` can do for you, that's just btw, why dont you call notifydatasetchanged() right after `audioFiles.remove(pos);` and why dont you fall also on `audioFiles.get(pos)` to get your item instead of using the `files` and after the `file.delete()` you can add this to check if it really is deleted `file.exist()` if not then you try to force delete. and pls try calling notifydatasetchanged after your remove and line and see if it makes a diff

Comment: Hi Elitz! :) I need to use my `files` so I can also delete it from the SD card, but is only getting the name and putting into a `String`... since I rely on reloading everything from scratch. But I do use `audioFiles.remove(pos)` in the click listener, so I know I'm removing the right one... I added `notifyDataSetChanged()` right after like you said, but still same problem. :( I did do the `file.exist` check and it came back false as it should. It really is a strange bug.

Comment: yeah really strange huh, upvote for that

Comment: I don't think I would have ever guessed that the `ViewHolder` would resist all the updating... funny... :)

Comment: lol, yeah, pretty weird, Android and its surprises . :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm check this out

in your `GridViewAudioAdapter.java`

```
public class GridViewAudioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AudioGridItem> {
private TextView audioTitleView; // look at this madam
int position;
```

in your `getView` method

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.audioViewFile = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_file);
holder.audioViewIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_icon);
audioTitleView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);
```

i do not have a good explanation as now i am assembling my thoughts, but the difference is, your `ImageView`s are **Ok** not your `TextView` so looking at your `getView` i will put the `TextView` declaration in the `ViewHolder` so your `getView` will look like this

```
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.audioViewFile = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_file);
holder.audioViewIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_icon);
holder.audioTitleView=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_title);
```

try and see if it helps

Comment: You did it again! I didn't put that in the holder, because for some reason I thought it was not needing it, since text is not loading for a long time. Crazy that that fixed it, you're awesome thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks to you too @NoniA.